# Clay-like physics in BGE

Tags: game-engine

I'm *also* trying to make some hands in the game engine, and I thought it would be really cool if they had something to do. So I say, "Hey! clay is fun!" but I can't figure out how to make the physics for clay in the game engine. All it does when I do soft-body for a cube is make it really bouncy. That's cool and all, but I want to make clay that I can squish the daylights out of with my bare-digital hands. Help?

Comment: Sadly I don't think this is possible... :/

Comment: :( found that out.

Comment: So you want something like "sculpt" inside the BGE?

Comment: Maybe you could use [metaballs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/metas/introduction.html)?

Comment: @seaturtle do you know of a good way to use meatballs I'm BGE?

Comment: Hm. Now that I'm playing around with it, I can't seem to get BGE physics working on metaballs. Darn.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you *can* use soft body physics for this. However, you'll need to lower the Shape Match threshold. (If you turn it off entirely, your shape will just crumple.)

[image: BGE softbody physics shape match threshold]

You'll also need to subdivide your cube a lot, if you haven't already done so. If you're using a modifier for this, you'll need to apply it.